# How to write a funtion that will check for the empty room in hotel in django

Tags: python, django

I am building a Hotel management system and I have writing a check_availability function that will check if a room is not empty depending of the category required by the client but it turns out that the database is ignore by the function cause it just care about the existing one not the added one.
here is the code:

from django.db import models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class RoomCategory(models.Model):
    name      = models.CharField(max_length=59)
    price     = models.IntegerField()
    beds      = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    capacity  = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    size      = models.CharField(max_length=59)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Room(models.Model):
    room_number = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    room_category = models.ForeignKey(RoomCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"The room {self.room_number} {self.room_category} has a maximum of {self.room_category.capacity} person and cost {self.room_category.price}/night "
    

class Booking(models.Model):
    customer  = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room      = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    check_in  = models.DateTimeField()
    check_out = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.customer} has booked for a {self.room} room from {self.check_in} to {self.check_out}"



    from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import BookingForm
from .models import Booking, RoomCategory, Room
from django.views.generic import FormView  
from Hotel.Availabililty.Available import check_availability
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

class BookingFormview(FormView):
    form_class      = BookingForm
    template_name   = 'Hotel/bookingformview.html'
    

    def form_valid(self, form):
        data             = form.cleaned_data
        roomlist         = Room.objects.filter(room_category__name=data['room'])
        for room in roomlist:
            booked_room = Booking.objects.filter(room__room_number=room.room_number) 
            available_rooms = []
            if room.room_number not in booked_room:
                available_rooms.append(room)
            else:
                if check_availability(room, data['check_in'], data['check_out']):
                    available_rooms.append(room)

        if len(available_rooms) > 0:
            room = available_rooms[0]
            new_booking = Booking.objects.create(
                customer=self.request.user,
                room=room,
                check_in=data['check_in'],
                check_out=data['check_out']
            )
            new_booking.save()
            return HttpResponse(new_booking)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('All the rooms of this type are not available')

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'Hotel/home.html')
```

the functions itself

```
from datetime import datetime
```

from Hotel.models import Booking, Room, RoomCategory

```
def check_availability(room, check_in, check_out):
    available_list = []
    booking list = Booking.objects.filter(room__room_category__name=room)
    for booking in booking list:
        if booking.check_in > check_out or booking.check_out < check_in:
            available_list.append(True)
        else:
            available_list.append(False)

    return all(available_list)
```

Comment: But based on your `room__room_category__name=room`, `room` is not a `Room` object, but the name of the `Category`? It also simply checks if at least one room is taken, if that is the case, all rooms are marked *occupied*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain the list of `Room`s for which no overlapping `Booking` exists with:

```
roomlist = Room.objects.filter(
    room_category__name=data['room']
).exclude(
    booking__check_in__lte=data['check_out'],
    booking__check_out__gte=data['check_in']
)
```

The logic is as follows, two intervals *[a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>]* and *[a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>]* do *not* overlap if *a<sub>1</sub>>b<sub>2</sub>*, or *b<sub>1</sub><a<sub>2</sub>*. So we can negate the logic, and thus two ranges *do* overal if *a<sub>1</sub>≤b<sub>2</sub>*, and *b<sub>1</sub>≥a<sub>2</sub>*.